# Can't get props to work by passing data through vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I found numorous of similar questions, tried almost all of them including defining `params` value as a string, and so on but still can't make it work.

I have defined the route to accept props as written on [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode):

```js
const routes = [
  ...
  ...
  {
    // this doesn't work, but passed on the url
    // path: '/profile/personal/update/:original',

    path: '/profile/personal/update',
    name: 'profile.personal.update',
    component: () => import('@/views/Profile/Personal/PersonalUpdate.vue'),
    props: true,
    // props: route => ({ default: route.params.original }), // this doesn't work
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
})

export default router
```

When I try to push the route and pass the data, typescript complains that I can't pass object to the `params` property, so I tried to cast it as `any` and `string` by doing like this, it passed:

```js
// Somewhere inside the usePersonalInfoComposition
const router = useRouter()

const personalInfo = reactive({
  data: new PersonalInfo(),
  isLoading: true,
})

const editPersonalInfo = () => {
  logger.info('Preparing data to be edited and redirect')
  router.push({
    name: 'profile.personal.update',
    params: {
      original: JSON.stringify(personalInfo.data)
      // original: personalInfo.data as any
    }
  })
}
```

However, when I try to grab the value of the prop which the value is given from route `params`, I got `undefined`.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: ['original'],
  setup(props) {
    const router = useRouter()

    const { personalInfo, updatePersonalInfo } = usePersonalInfoComposition()
    onBeforeMount(() => console.log(props.original)) // undefined
    onMounted(() => console.log(props.original)) // undefined

    // I would do this personally but it was kinda problematic
    // and error-prone especially when the page is refreshed.
    // So I decided to not doing it. Also, the `props` are now useless.
    onBeforeMount(() => {
      const original = router.currentRoute.value.params['original'] // "{ user: { id: 1, name: 'joe' } }"
      let parsed;

      // I need to do this since `params` returns either `string | string[]`
      if (original instanceof Array) parsed = JSON.parse(original[0])
      else parsed = JSON.parse(original)

      console.log(parsed) // { user: { id: 1, name: 'joe' } }
    })
  }
})
```

Is there any way to pass the `original` data without only passing `id` and make the user fetch the whole time they refreshes the page? I see Vuex has some solution for this, but I don't want to rebuild the whole app from scratch only for this kind of problem.

I was wondering about using local storage like sqlite or the browser's built in local storage but I think it will add more unnecessary complexity. How do you think?

Comment: What happen if you use another name for your param instead of :original? It seems that original might be a reserved keyword...

Comment: nothing happens, i tried something like `current`, `abc`, `foo`. still undefined

Answer (score 0):

After a while, It comes to a solution but with different approach to fix this problem. I'm not a state management expert but it works.

### Figuring out the problem

Let's say I have this on the personal info page:

`PersonalInfo.vue`

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'PersonalInfoPage',
  setup() {
    const {
      personalInfo,
      fetchPersonalInfo,
      editPersonalInfo,
    } = usePersonalInfoComposition()

    onBeforeMount(() => fetchPersonalInfo())

    return {
      personalInfo,
    }
  }
})
```

And an update page:

`PersonalInfoUpdate.vue`

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'PersonalInfoUpdatePage',
  setup() {
    const { personalInfo } = usePersonalInfoComposition()

    return {
      personalInfo,
    }
  }
})
```

Both has the same state being used, but from what I see, the composition was creating a new instance every time I call the method so the previously fetched state is not there and I need to re-fetch the same stuff all over again.

### Solution

Instead of doing it that way, I lifted the state up above the composition method to keep the fetched state and make a "getters" by using the `computed` property to be consumed inside my `PersonalUpdate.vue`

`PersonalInfoComposition.ts` -- before

```js
export const usePersonalInfoComposition = () => {
  const personalInfo = reactive({
    data: new PersonalInfo(),
    isLoading: true,
  })

  const editPersonalInfo = () => {
    router.push({
      name: 'profile.personal.update',
      params: {
        original: JSON.stringify(personalInfo.data),
      }
    })
  }

  const fetchPersonalInfo = () => {
    state.isLoading = true

    repository
      .fetch()
      .then(info => state.data = info)
      .catch(error => logger.error(error))
      .finally(() => state.isLoading = false)
  }

  return {
    personalInfo,
    fetchPersonalInfo,
    editPersonalInf,
  }
}
```

`PersonalInfoComposition.ts` -- after

```js
const state = reactive({
  data: new PersonalInfo(),
  isLoading: true,
})

export const usePersonalInfoComposition = () => {
  const personalInfo = computed(() => state.data)
  const isLoading = computed(() => state.isLoading)

  const editPersonalInfo = () => {
    router.push({ name: 'profile.personal.update' })
  }

  const fetchPersonalInfo = () => {
    state.isLoading = true

    repository
      .fetch()
      .then(info => state.data = info)
      .catch(error => logger.error(error))
      .finally(() => state.isLoading = false)
  }

  return {
    personalInfo,
    isLoading,
    fetchPersonalInfo,
    editPersonalInfo,
  }
}
```

Now it works, and no Vuex or local storage or even `route.params` needed.

### The Downside

Since the state is shared, whenever I made any changes on the state attached to a `v-model`, the data inside the `PersonalInfo.vue` are also be changed.

This could be easily fixed by creating a clone of the state object to handle the updates and sync it whenever the new data persisted in the database.

`PersonalInfoComposition.ts` --  fixing the downside

```js
const state = reactive({
  data: new PersonalInfo(),
  isLoading: true,
})

const editState = reactive({
  data: new PersonalInfo(),
  isLoading: true,
})

export const usePersonalInfoComposition = () => {
  const personalInfo = computed(() => state.data)
  const personalInfoClone = computed(() => editState.data)
  const isLoading = computed(() => state.isLoading)
  const editIsLoading = computed(() => editState.isLoading)

  const editPersonalInfo = () => {
    // This will clone the object as well as its reactivity, dont do this
    // editState.data = state.data

    // Clone the object and remove its reactivity
    editState.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.data))
    router.push({ name: 'profile.personal.update' })
  }

  const fetchPersonalInfo = () => {
    state.isLoading = true

    repository
      .fetch()
      .then(info => state.data = info)
      .catch(error => logger.error(error))
      .finally(() => state.isLoading = false)
  }

  const updatePersonalInfo = () => {
    editState.isLoading = true

    repository
      .update(editState.data.id)
      .then(info => {
        // This could be extracted to a new method, but keep it simple for now
        state.data = info
        if (state.data === info) router.back()
      })
      .catch(error => logger.error(error))
      .finally(() => editState.isLoading = false)
  }

  return {
    personalInfo,
    personalInfoClone,
    isLoading,
    editIsLoading,
    fetchPersonalInfo,
  }
}
```